# How to choose random children

Tags: javascript, html

I have following Problem: 
I have no clue how I let JavaScript delete a random Child.
I have a `DIV` (gets randomly chosen). In this `DIV` are more `DIV`s and I want a JavaScript function that deletes one or two `DIV`s. But there is one `DIV` in there that shouldn't be deleted. For now I have this:

```js
if (spieleranzahl == 4) {
    var del = document.getElementById(random)
    if(del.hasChildNodes()){
        let rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); 
        del.removeChild(del.childNodes[rdm]);
    }
    if(del.hasChildNodes()){
        let mdr = Math.floor(Math.random()* 3); 
        del.removeChild(del.childNodes[mdr]);
    }
}
```

thanks for Answers.

Comment: It's unclear what your code intends to do: (1) what does `random` refer to? And why do you have two blocks of almost identical `if` statements?

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/buft78k5/) to exemplify the use of `children` and `childNodes`. The answer from @nicolas is another way of selecting a node from the DOM, in his case using a CSS Seelctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `:nth-child` selector to get yourself a random child.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = () => {
  let parentSelector = document.querySelector('.parent');
  // we want to make sure we get a random number between 1 and the number of child.
  let random = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * parentSelector.childElementCount);
  child = document.querySelector('.parent>span:nth-child(' + random + ')');
  if(child) {
    console.log(child);
    child.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>child #1</span>
  <span>child #2</span>
  <span>child #3</span>
  <span>child #4</span>
  <span>child #5</span>
  <span>child #6</span>
  <span>child #7</span>
</div>

<button class="btn">Delete a child !</button>
```

Comment: You can also count the children, better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I highly suggest you post an answer on this topic, so i can compare it with what i've done here. @anwerj

Comment: You clearly have made it generic enough, just hard coded the count of span to 7. It's a good answer thus doesn't want to post another.

Comment: You could use childNodes.length with the math.random to make sure the child node always exists

Answer (score 0):

I Understand from your question that you need to remove two elements at a time, leaving only the last element

```
<script>
function remove(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].children;
  if(elements.length  == 1)
    return;

  elements[getRandom(elements.length-1)].remove();
  if(elements.length > 1){
    elements[getRandom(elements.length-1)].remove();
  }
}

function getRandom(max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 0 + 1)) + 0;
}

</script>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<button onclick="remove();" >Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), you can accomplish this like so:

```
var randomDivChild = rando(document.querySelectorAll('.parent>div'));
if(randomDivChild) randomDivChild.remove();
```

Nothing else needed. Check out the site for documentation if needed, but it's pretty straightforward.